# How to display the "homepage" option in default comment form in Drupal7?

Tags: forms, drupal-7, comments

How to display the "homepage" option in a default comment form?
After I install the Drupal7, the comment form only has three fields, "Your name", "Subject", and "Comment".
I know the comment module has the "homepage" field in the database. But how to display it on the page?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the field that is already there in Drupal core, you need to allow the anonymous poster to leave their contact information.

**Navigate to:**
Administration » Structure » Content types » (*Your content type*) » Comment Settings » Anonymous commenting

Choose *Anonymous posters **may** leave their contact info* 
or *Anonymous posters **must** leave their contact info*

If you don't want the email field to display, you can hide it using a simple form alter or by setting it to `display: none;` in CSS.  Just make sure that if you do that, you set the setting above to **may** rather than **must**, or your commenter won't be able to post their comment!

Answer (score 0):

that's very simple. Via admin interface (/admin/structure/types/manage//comment/fields , you can add as many field as you want. and in next tab, Comment display, you can manage display of these fields.

Comment: thanks for your reply,I know what you say.But somewhere are not custom fields,like the comment form on the page [link](http://www.drupalcoder.com/blog/drupal-7-book-review-drupal-7-module-development).I think the "homepage" option is from the Drupal comment core module,no custom field.

Comment: well, if you want to know to it was done in this particular case,  as dropalcoder.com. It's might be even not seven, but drupal 6 - don't know.

Comment: um...It's possible.Thanks again.Can I ask you another question?If I add a new commet form field named "Homepage",how should I do in order to filter the data from the "Homepage" field?

Comment: not sure I understood you..
if you want to validate it's data or collect it or something - you need to do this via custom module and hook_form_validate